# Each not encapsulating blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I'm building a site that dynamically positions content in the middle of a group of sections.

Div with image background (Full width image - FWI)

Div with image background (of different height)

My problem is even with the each selector the first div is used to dictate the height to any other divs below it, I'm obviously missing something pretty basic

Jquery

```
jQuery(window).on("resize", function() {
  jQuery('.fwi').each(function() {
    jQuery('.image-outer').height(jQuery('.fwi-image').height());
  });
}).resize();


jQuery(".fwi-image img").load(function() {
  jQuery('.fwi').each(function() {
    jQuery('.image-outer').height(jQuery('.fwi-image').height());
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fwi">
    <div class="relative">      
          <div class="fwi-image full-width">
                <img width="1920" height="1080" src="">
          </div>  
          <div class="outer image-outer" style="height: 1080px;">
          my content which is dynamically positioned in the center vertically in my div
          </div>
   </div>
 </div>


<div class="fwi">
    <div class="relative">      
          <div class="fwi-image full-width">
                <img width="1920" height="1200" src="">
          </div>  
          <div class="outer image-outer" style="height: 1080px;">
         will take height from previous image-outer not its parent - it should be 1200
          </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Here is the site:

You can see the second picture block the text is sitting too low, because its taking the size of the first picture block
http://prestlaundry.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in you document.

```
function adjustImageOuterHeight () {
    var fwiImage = jQuery(this).parent(".fwi-image");
    var imageOuter = fwiImage.next(".image-outer");
    imageOuter.height(fwiImage.height());
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".fwi-image img")
        .load(adjustImageOuterHeight)
        .each(function () {
            if (this.complete) adjustImageOuterHeight.call(this);
        });
});

jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    jQuery(".fwi-image img").each(adjustImageOuterHeight);
});
```

Loose any other jQuery stuff related to `.fwi-image`. And optionally loose your explicit call to `.resize()` on the `window` object.

Comment: That doesnt solve my problem though because each of these sections could be in a different location in my DOM - due to different page layouts

Is there anyway the ('this') selector could be used?

Comment: Oh, I see, `load` event handler for the images is registered too late, after they're loaded.

Comment: Perfect, sorry for the delay someone managed to get malware onto my production server and I've been flat tack cleaning it. you're a star!